# Accelerating rigid stick

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, reference-frames, mass, acceleration

I have read that in relativity, an infinitely rigid stick cannot be accelerated.

So, I wonder what rigidity a massless stick of the length 1 m should have so to resist acceleration like a body of the mass of 1 kg?

Also, I wonder, whether rigidity can be a the fundamental source of mass.

Comment: A massless object has no resistance to acceleration

Comment: @AdrianHoward a rigid object cannot be accelerated by applying force to one of its points. This means, it resists acceleration.

Comment: I understand the rigid body dynamics. Resisting acceleration from a point force due to perfect rigidity having an infinite speed of sound. But if you consider it massless there can be no action reaction pair to the force.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limited notion of [rigid motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rigidity) in relativity. In principle you can rigidly accelerate an extended object, but only via precisely applied forces spread across its whole bulk. If you push or pull it in some other way, it will still accelerate, but the way it accelerates won't meet the definition of rigid motion. It isn't possible to construct an object that can only be accelerated rigidly.

Comment: I am asking about theoretical rigid stick, not real one from atoms. What resistance force will it produce when accelerated?

Comment: @Anixx There's no such thing as a theoretical rigid stick in relativity. What you read is incorrect, or you misinterpreted it. If you link your source, we might be able to tell you which.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you heard it a little wrong. There is no such thing as a rigid stick. A stick is made of atoms connected by bonds. Bonds exert electromagnetic forces on neighboring atoms, and those forces cannot travel faster than light.

So if you accelerate one end, one atom pulls on the next. The forces between atoms change. The other end does not begin to accelerate until the changed forces propagate there. The stick changes shape.

Comment: I am asking about theoretical rigid stick.